# wpdb query to insert images in to post/page gallery

Tags: database, query, gallery

Can someone please help me find a way to insert images in to a post/pages photo **GALLERY** with a database query. I am currently using a function to insert images into the database and give them a parent ID. Thus, allowing them to show on the correct page. However, I have multiple images for each of my products. So this isn't a feasible ends to solve my problem.

It is of some importance that advisers know I'm working with the woocommerce plugin. Might change some of the tactics?

To better explain:

I have a directory that has been placed in the uploads folder, full of product information and images. The script checks the subdirectories against the database and inserts the images to the correct product. Ergo, if there are multiple images, my script doesn't work. I need a why to put the images into a **GALLERY** via script. SQL, PHP, JavaScript.... I don't care. Just need help! :-)

Thanks for your help! And below is an example of my script.

```
    function insertImagesIntoDatabase(array $idsAndKey, array $images)
{

  // Get the keys and id associations
  foreach($idsAndKey as $keyId => $id)
  {
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Key value: ' . $key;
    echo '<br>';
    echo 'Page ID: ' . $value;
    echo '<br>';

    //Start a forloop to match the image keys with the id keys.
    foreach($images as $keyImage => $image)
    {
      //if statement to check if the keys match. If the do, insert the image into the database.
      if($keyId === $keyImage)
      {

        echo 'Page ID match: ' . $id;

        //Change the image string to an array.
        $imageArrayExplode = explode(", ", $image);

        //Loop through the images to insert them into the database
        foreach($imageArrayExplode as $eachImage)
        {

          //define images to look for
          $jpegSearch = strpos($eachImage, 'jpeg');
          $jpgSearch = strpos($eachImage, 'jpg');
          $pngSearch = strpos($eachImage, 'png');

          //declare what type of file the images are.
          if($jpegSearch)
          {
            $post_mime_type =  'image/jpeg';
          }
          elseif ($jpgSearch)
          {
            $post_mime_type =  'image/jpg';
            continue;
          }
          else
          {
            $post_mime_type = 'image/png';
            continue;
          }

          echo '<br>';
          echo 'Inserting Image: ' . $eachImage;
          echo '<br>';
          echo 'Image type: ' . $post_mime_type;
          echo '<br>';

          //Attachment arguments to add the image to its parent.
          $attachment = array(
            'guid' => $eachImage,
            'post_mime_type' => $post_mime_type,
            'post_title' => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($eachImage)),
            'post_content'  => '',
            'post_status' => 'inherit'
          );

          //Insert the attachment
          $image_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $eachImage, $id);

          // Make sure that this file is included, as wp_generate_attachment_metadata() depends on it.
          require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

          // Generate the metadata for the attachment, and update the database record.
          $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($image_id, $eachImage);

          wp_update_attachment_metadata($image_id, $attach_data);

          set_post_thumbnail($id, $image_id);
        }
      }

    }
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** My script works fine. Just need a way to relate the images to the gallery.

Comment: Why don't you want to use built-in functions instead of complex MySQL queries? Do you have multiple images for multiple posts? Please edit your question adding more information.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple images for multiple post. Doing a MySQL query, hard coded, isn't fun with wordpress. I would much rather use a function like I did in my script to query the database. Thanks!